# Discrepancy between question header and close banner on months ago calculation

Tags: bug, questions, closed-questions, user-interface

Today I was doing some moderation on [is there a difference between software architecture and web development architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74292775/is-there-a-difference-between-software-architecture-and-web-development-architec) and saw that the question header shows the question was asked 5 months ago, but the close banner shows that the question was closed 6 months ago.

The question was asked on November 2nd, 5 months ago, and was closed on November 3rd (one day later). This could be due to discrepancies in how the values are calculated (e.g. rounding may occur).

This should probably be adjusted so that both places use the same method of relative date calculation.

[image: picture showing the question header and close modal]

I have included freehand red circles for easier debugging.